# Repeat use of quote marks around unusual usage of a word

Tags: punctuation, quotation-marks

I'm currently reading a legal document which refers to 'wet' shipping/work/practices. In the first instance, the meaning of 'wet' is explained. Can the quote marks be omitted thereafter?

Comment: If you're _reading_ it, that means someone else has already written and somehow publicised it. How would you drop the quote marks in something you're reading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Punctuation is a matter of style, and as such the writer is guided by the governing manual of style. I use the *Chicago Manual of Style*, which recommends that technical terms appear in italic when they're defined and in roman thereafter. When the term is a specialized use of a common word, the recommendation is place the the word in quotes instead. Presumably, the quotes are unnecessary thereafter. But bear in mind that you're reading a legal document, and lawyers are fond of redundancy to make things clear. If there's the slightest chance that *wet work* might be interpreted differently from *"wet" work*, a lawyer will prefer the latter to the former.